# I can't seem to import pyfetch from 'pyodide.http'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyodide

First thing first, i'm somewhat extremely new to python and jupyter and ohter stuff.
So i'm enrolling in this Python for data science class from cognitiveclass.ai . currently at Module 4 - Working with Data in Python and theres this lab exercise where it imported pyfetch and it works just fine no error. then i try it in my jupyter notebook and 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodide' ...

as any other person here i google this problem and i found that if a module not found, we could just go to the terminal and download the module name with pip or pip3. and here i'm not sure if i have import/download pyfetch or pyodide itself supposed to be a package provided *virtually* or something like that. so that it i guess.

please ask me more cause i'm also not entirely sure what else i should clarify about this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Pyodide is loaded from a JavaScript file. It is loaded in the HTML `<head>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.3/full/pyodide.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="msg">Loading page ...</div>
  <br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        async function main() {
                let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
                // Add more code
        }

      main();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that your notebook is running Python in the browser with WebAssembly using the [Pyodide project](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/).

[pyfetch](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/python-api/http.html#pyodide.http.pyfetch) function is part of the Pyodide core package, and indeed you cannot currently install it outside of the browser with pip. This is a bug, and we will address it in https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/1839 after with you will be able to install it with,

```
pip install pyodide-core-py
```

Meanwhile, you can run your notebook in other notebook environments that uses Pyodide such as [JupyterLite](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

So overall it's a valid usability issue and something that needs improving.